# Как Enter настроить

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

Как настроить так чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на Enter сайт проверял правильно ли введены данные если правильно то заходил в систему. (Не кликая мышью на войти, как в ВК). Это джаваскрипт? Могли бы вы с кодом помочь?

Comment: Да по идее оно всегда на `Enter` срабатывает..

Comment: нет(((((((((((((((((((((